# center and radius of convergence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

center and radius of convergence
of following summation :

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)^{n+2}\left(\frac{x-3}{2}\right)^{n(n+1)}$$

I think we can use root test , so we must compute following limit :

$$
\begin{aligned}
L &=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left|(n+1)^{n+2}\left(\frac{x-3}{2}\right)^{n(n+1)} \right|^{\frac{1}{n}} \\
&
\end{aligned}
$$
Now we must find all $x$ such that $L=0$ .

Answer (score 2):

Well, we have\begin{align}\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left|(n+1)^{n+2}\left(\frac{x-3}{2}\right)^{n(n+1)} \right|^{\frac{1}{n}}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}(n+1)^{1+2/n}\left|\frac{x-3}2\right|^{n+1}\\&=\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }\left|\frac{x-3}2\right|<1(\iff|x-3|<2)\\\infty&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}\end{align}So, the radius of convergence is $2$.

Comment: Why if $\left|\frac{x-3}2\right|<1$ this limit is $0$ ?

Comment: @1200785626 It is because $\left|\frac{x-3}{2}\right|^n$ decays exponentially fast (with respect to $n$) if $\left|\frac{x-3}{2}\right|<1$, and an exponential decay times a polynomial growth decays to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Puting $\;q:=\cfrac{|x-3|}2\;$ , we get that if $\;q\ge1\;$ then

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(n+1)^{1+2/n}q^{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}(n+1)(n+1)^{2/n}q^{n+1}=\infty\cdot1\cdot\infty=\infty$$

whereas if $\;q<1\;$ then we can write $\;q=\cfrac1a\;,\;\;a>1\;$ , so

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(n+1)^{1+2/n}q^{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}(n+1)(n+1)^{2/n}q^{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+1}{a^n}(n+1)^{2/n}q$$

and using L'Hospital's rule:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x+1}{a^x}\stackrel{\frac\infty\infty}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac1{a^x\ln a}=0$$

so the second limit above is thus zero since $\;(n+1)^{2/n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1\;$

Comment: I think $n$ on the RHS of L'Hôpital shoud be $x$.